# Python 3 - Create global Button with name from string Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Okay, so I started programming Minesweeper. For that, I need a variable number of Buttons (or should I use something different).
So I got two loops which should create a button with a name. But I need the buttons of course to have other names. So f.i.:
the first button = button_1
the second button = button_2
...

My code goes so:

```
class test(Tk):
   def __init__(self):
      self.frame_game = Frame(self)
      for i in range(1, height):
           for j in range(1, height):
               # here i need the button to be created
```

I tried it with:

```
globals()['Button_' + str(i) + str(j)] = Button(...)
```

but that doesn't work because I need a button which is global.

I also tried it with

```
vars(self)['Button_' + str(i) + str(j)] = Button(self.frame_game, text='0').pack()
```

I pack the label later with:

```
self.frame_game.pack()
```

It doesn't throw an Exception.

Anyone got an idea?

EDIT:
IT WORKS!!!!
The code just didnt go into the loop.
changed it to

```
for i in range(0, height):
```

Also of course the other loop with j.
The working code is in the loop following:

```
vars(self)['Button_' + str(i) + str(j)] = Button(self.frame_game, text='0').pack()
```

Comment: any time you need to dynamically create buttons, labels or other objects its probably best to use a list. Your list can be in the global namespace and you can simply append the list with new objects and reference them later.

Comment: Use a `list` or `dict` to host your dynamically created objects instead of dynamically injecting them to your `globals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never create variables like this. It makes your code very difficult to read, very difficult to debug.

Instead, store the widgets in a list or dictionary. Since you want to reference them by name, a dictionary works best:

```
self.buttons = {}
for i in range(1, height):
    for j in range(1, height):
        name = "Button_{}_{}".format(i,j)
        button = Button(...)
        button.pack()
        self.buttons[name] = button
```

With the above, you can later reference the buttons like `self.buttons["Button_1_1"]`, etc.

Also, in your code you're doing something like `Button(...).pack()`. `.pack()` returns `None`, so you're setting all of your variables to `None`.  If you want to save references to your buttons, you need to call `pack` (or `grid` or `place`) in a separate statement from where you create the button.

Answer (score 1):

- You can declare the global button as follows:
- set a global variable name for the button

```
global myBtn
myBtn = Button(root, text = "This is a global button")
```

Thank you
Mohamed Elghobary